# How to setup java on freebsd?

Tags: java, freebsd, ports

I have both Java JRE and Java JDK on a FreeBSD 7.2 box (running PFSense) from http://www.freebsdfoundation.org/downloads/java.shtml

```
find / -name gives me output like:
/usr/local/diablo-jre1.6.0/bin/java
/usr/local/diablo-jdk1.6.0/bin/java
/usr/local/diablo-jdk1.6.0/jre/bin/java
```

so I make a link to /usr/local/bin like so:

```
 ln /usr/local/diablo-jre1.6.0/bin/java /usr/local/bin/java
```

and now I get

```
# rehash
# java
Error: could not find libjava.so
Error: could not find Java 2 Runtime Environment.
```

SOOOOOO, I'm wondering if there is some tool I can use to turn on a particular java vm similar to Ubuntus' /etc/jvm?

Comment: You'll get more help on superuser.com

Comment: This question belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Yasir I need to keep up on the new stackexchange sites!

Comment: Yea, I didn't even know there was a unix.stackexchange.com site....  I decided stackoverflow vs superuser because I figured developers would know how to change out the jvm better than the admins.

Comment: @Mark0978: Chances are it'll turn out JVM doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: It could belong on a number of sites.  I can't decide if its OT for here or not, since you're installing the JDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/usr/local/diablo-jre1.6.0/bin/java` application probably locates `libjava.so` relative to the location of the `java` application itself.  By creating a hard link to `java` and executing it via that hard link, you've probably broken that mechanism.

Suggestions:

- Put `/usr/local/diablo-jre1.6.0/bin` on your search path.
- Create an alias for `java` instead of a link.
- Replace the hard link with a symbolic link; i.e. use `ln -s` to create it.

Answer (score 2):

The FreeBSD packages should have installed a wrapper-script in /usr/local/bin/java that knows about the different installed JVMs, and their JAVA_HOMEs etc. Did you by chance accidentally download the tarball instead of the package?

What does `pkg_info | grep jdk` yield?

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a jail, you may need to move /proc temporarily so it doesn't try to use it to find out where the Java libraries are. Got bitten by this one!